# Android resize image to fit imageview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, imageview

I get an image from file chooser and I put it into imageview. I want the image to be fully visible even if it is larger than the image view. At the moment, it looks like below. The image is cropped on all sides

[image]

Here is xml of imageview

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fl_book_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/add_book_header_image_height"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_book_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorImageViewBackground"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_add_update_book"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:padding="@dimen/add_update_book_icon_padding"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_vector_add_photo" />
</FrameLayout>
```

First ImageView is the one that contains cover, second one is that little edit pen in right bottom corner

Comment: Use Picasso or Glide and they'll give you the options for doing this easily and properly without running into memory issues.

Comment: It might be a better experience for the user if they can't see the eldritch horror in its entirety, that can lead to problems

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [`CENTER_INSIDE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType)  or `FIT_CENTER`, which both maintain the aspect ratio but scale it down so it fits within the view bounds. `FIT_CENTER` will also scale **up** if the image is smaller than the view. If `FIT_XY` didn't change anything, I'm guessing you're setting the image source in code - you'll probably need to `invalidate()` the `ImageView` so it can recalculate its sizes and redraw.

But like @Tenfour04 says, a library like Glide will take care of a lot of this for you, and it'll be safer and more performant if you're potentially dealing with large images - e.g. if they're user-provided, or you're using high-res images so they look good on higher-end devices, but also want to support low-end devices that would struggle with large bitmaps.

You can handle that yourself - [here's the docs on it](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap), but they recommend using a library like Glide themselves!

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:scaleType="fitxy"`

You can find more information here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: I've tried it before and it didn't work. The result was the same

Answer (score 0):

Following @Tenfour04 and @cactustictacs advice I made a Glide function which looks like this.

```
fun loadBookPicture(image: Any, imageView: ImageView)
{
    try
    {
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(image)
            .fitCenter()
            .into(imageView) // the view in which the image will be loaded
    }
    catch (e: IOException)
    {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

And I removed `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` and `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` from ImageView xml because it apparently overrides Glide